# angular js dialog popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" 
        ng-model="alert.acknowledged" 
        ng-disabled="alert.acknowledged" 
        ng-click="onacknowledgedClick(alert)">
</td>
```

I have a checkbox for acknowledged column, when the user clicks on the checkbox, it has display a dialog pop up asking for do you want to acknowledge through phone, text or email?

Can someone help me with the Angular JS concept? I am new to this.

Comment: ng-change is more preferred here instead of click.

Comment: It would help if you showed the function and asked a clear question. What is it doing/not doing and what should it be doing instead?

Comment: Show us what generates the popup

Comment: It should show the dialog pop up with 3 radio buttons text, phone or email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('app','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']).controller("Hello",function($scope,$modal){
$scope.selectedAckOption ="NONE";
$scope.onacknowledgedClick=function(al) {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'stackedModal.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size:'md',
  resolve: {}
});
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $scope.selectedAckOption = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
};
}).controller("ModalInstanceCtrl",function($scope,$modalInstance){
  $scope.saveOption = function() {
   $modalInstance.close($scope.ackOption);
 };
});
```

Complete solution - https://plnkr.co/edit/VnAv67AMrykf6CEyrAiv?p=preview

Comment: @puneethSrikanta welcome. mark it as answer if it helped solve your issue.